# Oracle sqlplus - defining typed table with no attributes but nested tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, object-relational-model

I have an problem with my homework. I have the following type definitions:

```
-- Type definitions
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE languages_table_t AS TABLE of VARCHAR2(20);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE phones_table_t AS TABLE of NUMBER;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tourist_t AS OBJECT (
  -- ...
  -- some simple attrubutes
  -- one attribute of user defined type
  -- more simple attrubutes
  -- ...
) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE guide_t UNDER tourist_t (
  languages   languages_table_t,
  phones      phones_table_t
);
/
-- All types are created successfully


-- table definitions:

CREATE TABLE Tourist OF tourist_t (
  -- all simple attributes with nullity constraints
  CONSTRAINT PK_TOURIST PRIMARY KEY (username),
) NESTED TABLE the_UDT_attr STORE AS the_user_defined_type;
-- Created successfully

CREATE TABLE Guide OF guide_t (
  CONSTRAINT PK_GUIDE PRIMARY KEY (username)
) NESTED TABLE languages STORE AS guide_languages
  NESTED TABLE phones STORE AS guide_phones;
-- returns mystic error
```

when running the last create instruction, I get the following error:

```
CREATE TABLE Guide OF guide_t (
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22913: must specify table name for nested table column or attribute
```

I've searched for this error, but it seems too specific to my definitions, and I couldn't find how to solve it. Please, any help will be appreciated. I need an idea about how to attack these kind of errors, how to solve them or where to read about it.

The version of sqlplus is:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

If you need any other info to help me, please ask, and I'll update the question.

Thanks!

Comment: Your example worked for me after I added a real column to `tourist_t`.  Are you sure that all types created successfully?  Some IDEs, such as PL/SQL Developer, will execute a `create type` statement but not warn you of the exceptions.

Comment: @jonearles: Yes, I'm sure they are created successfully. I'm not using IDEs, but loading the scripts in the sqlplus CLI with the notation `@script.sql`. So far, I think it may be some remains of old runs, and  maybe I'm not working on a clean environment, but I'm not familiar with oracle administration. Is there a way to clean the session and start again with a clean environment?

Comment: Since your scripts don't have schema names, you should be able to run them as any user, on any database.  To start over, you can run a script like this: `drop table guide;
drop type guide_t;
drop type tourist_t;
drop type phones_table_t;
drop type languages_table_t;`.  With your code, `tourist_t` should be failing with `PLS-00589: no attributes found in object type "TOURIST_T"`.

Comment: @jonearles: also, in my script, `tourist_t` has many columns. The one that doesn't have is the **table** `guide`, which has only nested table attributes. You can see the real script in [my repo](https://github.com/throoze/rtu) (in spanish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested table storage also needs to be defined for the attributes of the supertype.  The udt_tables.sql script works when I add this to line 155:

```
CREATE TABLE Guia OF guia_t (
  CONSTRAINT PK_GUIA PRIMARY KEY (username)
) NESTED TABLE idiomas STORE AS guia_idiomas
  NESTED TABLE telefonos STORE AS guia_telefonos
  NESTED TABLE tipoHitosPreferidos STORE as something;
```

Comment: Thanks! my lab partner just figured it out, and I was looking the question to update it. Thanks for taking time to help us!